# Validation for Master card format

Tags: javascript, regex

I need auto-created space each 4 numbers for my input. This is my code:

```js
const [deposit, setDeposit] = useState('');
const [withdrawal, setWithdrawal] = useState('');
const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = useState('');
const inputValidation = event => {
const onlyNumbers = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
const creditNumberCorrectFormat = '';
if (event.target.value === '' || onlyNumbers.test(event.target.value)) {
    if (event.target.name === 'cardNumber') {
        setCardNumber(event.target.value);
    } else {
        setDeposit(event.target.value);
        setWithdrawal(event.target.value);
    }
}
```

Here, I can type only numbers.
I need to enter card number this format 1111 2222 3333 4444. Auto-created space each 4 numbers

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need to enter card number this format 1111 2222 3333 4444. Auto-created space each 4 numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a regexp like this:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

input.addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
  const { value } = evt.target;
  const formattedValue = value.replace(/\s?/g, '').replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
  
  output.value = formattedValue;
});
```

```html
<label>Input:</label><input id='input' type='number' />
<label>Output:</label><input id='output' readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Number Format, it's a great component for Number Inputs, and they already have masking support for credit card numbers, take a look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format#format-with-mask--format-credit-card-in-an-input)

```
<NumberFormat format="#### #### #### ####" mask="_"/>
```